# Electron window unable to be resized after being set to minimum sizing

Tags: angularjs, electron

Edit: I recently upgraded my version of Electron and it fixed itself.

I recently set up my electron app so that the Browser Window has a minHeight/minWidth of ~900-400 px.

```
private createWindow(): void {
   this._window = new BrowserWindow({
      width: this.browserWidth,
      height: this.browserHeight,
      minWidth: this.browerMinWidth,
      minHeight: this.breowserMinHeight,
      webPreferences: {
         nodeIntegration: true
      }
   });
}
```

Since that change, when the window is at it's minimum size (height, width, or both), the zone to turn the mouse pointer into a resizing mouse pointer seems to only be about 1px wide, making it almost impossible to grab. Strangely, this only effects the bottom and right side border. Any ideas/thoughts on a fix? Thanks.